# Как рассчитать сложную скидку?

Tags: алгоритм

Интересуют методы для расчета стоимости корзины, набранной клиентом в интернет магазине. Пусть есть несколько акций, которые дают скидку на определенные товары или по некоторым условиями, однако могут быть ситуации, когда на группу товаров может воздействовать несколько скидок, в этом случае применяется только одна, а не все сразу.

Получается какая-то сложная и запутанная логика и код смотрится ужасно. Есть ли какие-то приемы или модели, позволявшие описать систему правил скидок наглядно? Может что-то из теории графов использовать?

Есть идея - оперировать списками, пропуская список товаров через обработчики. Обработчик может изменить цену одному товару или даже "объединить" несколько товаров, в один псевдотовар со своей ценой.

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях магазины пишут "Скидки не суммируются. Применяется наибольшая скидка к каждому товару по отдельности"

Comment: Я имел ввиду приемы для реализации механизма скидок в коде, может паттерны какие-то или принципы

Comment: Не очень понимаю, почему сложная логика. Мне представляется так: 1. посмотреть 1-й товар в корзине, 2. получить все скидки на него, 3. выбрать нужную, 4. добавить к товару. И так для всех позиций в корзине. И все это отдельными строчками в таблице заказа сохранить. Чтобы потом, когда акция пропадет, не потерять стоимость прошлого заказа.